# How to assign header to a data frame?

Tags: r

I have the following (just a part of the code)

```
         dat <-  rbind(dat,sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files_list[i]))))
    }
     data.frame(id,dat)
```

but I get the following. How can I change the header of second column to "value"?

```
   id X1041L
1  2   1041
2  4    474
3  8    192
4 10    148
5 12     96
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `names<-` assignment function

```
names(dat)[2] <- "value"
```

You could also use `setNames`, which is basically the same thing as `names<-`, but the changed data is returned as the result.

```
setNames(dat, c(names(dat)[1], "value"))
```

**Update:** To avoid some of the copying made by `names`, you can also use `attr<-`

```
attr(dat, "names")[2] <- "value"
```

And as mentioned by Ananda in the comments, for no copying, `data.table` can be used

```
library(data.table)
setnames(dat, "X1041L", "value")
```

Here's a look at the copying:

```
> tracemem(dat)
# [1] "<0x23289b0>"
> names(dat)[2] <- "value"
# tracemem[0x23289b0 -> 0x26a1270]: 
# tracemem[0x26a1270 -> 0x2244030]: 
# tracemem[0x2244030 -> 0x26b9508]: 
> tracemem(dat)
# [1] "<0x26b9508>"
> attr(dat, "names")[2] <- "value"
# tracemem[0x26b9508 -> 0x23dbd50]: 
> library(data.table)
> tracemem(dat)
# [1] "<0x28c4408>"
> setnames(dat, "X1041L", "value")
```

Comment: It may seem like overkill to load a package for something like this, but `setnames` from "data.table" would achieve this without making copies. Experiment using `tracemem(dat); names(dat)[2] <- "value"` compared with `tracemem(dat); setnames(dat, "X1041L", "value")`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - point taken, but I could also use `attr(dat, "names")[2] <- "value"` to avoid some copying from `names`.  Although DT still wins. :-)